# I can`t import scikit -learn on python3. how can i import it?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, installation, pycharm

I installed numpy-1.13.1+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win32 .whl and scipy-0.19.1-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl successfully, then I installed scikit-learn successfully, but when I ran import sklearn, 
pycharm gave me errors. How can I remove this problem?
I installed python3.6 (32bit) on  windows 10 (64bit).

```
import sklearn
```

result of run:

```
C:\Users\Emertat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe "F:/Python/NS videos/cedes/Exercise 07 test.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Python/NS videos/cedes/Exercise 07 test.py", line 21, in <module>
    import sklearn
  File "C:\Users\Emertat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 134, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Users\Emertat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .utils.fixes import signature
  File "C:\Users\Emertat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .validation import (as_float_array,
  File "C:\Users\Emertat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 18, in <module>
    from ..utils.fixes import signature
  File "C:\Users\Emertat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 144, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\Emertat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py", line 117, in <module>
    from .matfuncs import *
  File "C:\Users\Emertat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\matfuncs.py", line 19, in <module>
    import scipy.special
  File "C:\Users\Emertat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py", line 640, in <module>
    from ._ufuncs import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Your scipy-install is broken. But analysis is hard for us given that sparse info. Do yourself a favor and use the anaconda-distribution.

Comment: Try to remove Matlab from your path.

Answer (score 0):

First, **Remove the sklearn** form your Windows OS by using the following command-

```
pip uninstall scikit-learn
```

Then, you need to **install** [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) and [scipy](https://www.scipy.org/) from their own official installers.

Wheel packages (.whl files) for scikit-learn from [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/) can be installed with the [pip](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installing/) utility. Open a console and type the following to install or upgrade scikit-learn to the latest stable release:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

If there are no binary packages matching your python, version you might to try to install scikit-learn and its dependencies from [christoph gohlke unofficial windows installers](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-learn) or from a [python distribution](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/advanced_installation.html#install-by-distribution) instead.